# Meaning of the phrase: "on the basis of symptoms"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I cannot understand the meaning of this expression.

> The patient cohort was composed of individuals
> with known cancers, most diagnosed **on the basis of symptoms of**
> disease.

"on the basis of symptoms of" means when cancer just became symptomatic?

Answer (score 0):

The words combine into phrases differently. You should understand "on the basis of" as grouping with "diagnosed." A diagnosis—in this case, doctors deciding that a patient has cancer—has a "basis," a reason for that decision. This sentence is saying that most of these patients were diagnosed "based on" the fact that they showed symptoms of the disease.

Comment: As opposed to their blood results for instance.

Comment: @mdewey Or biopsies, probably. My point is that instead of seeing the phrase "on the basis of symptoms," we should see the phrases "diagnosed on the basis of" and "symptoms of the disease."